# backslash n(\n) does't working on show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

backslash n(\n) does't working on print

create post :

[image: create post]

calling post(index.html.erb) :

[image]

index.html.erb:

```
<%= section.short_content %>
```

create.html.erb:

```
<%= f.text_area :short_content ,:class=>'form-control',:placeholder=>'ShortContent',:rows=>10%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) to format output.

```
<%= simple_format(section.short_content) %>
```